# minecraftserver.jar won't open with edited server.properties file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

[image: this is the error it gives me]

My Minecraft server doesn't open anymore. The first 2 times it worked, but when I try to run it with a edited server properties file it won't open.

I already tried the .exe but that doesn't work either.

How can I make it run?

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why your server isn't running:

```
[22:51:00] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[22:51:00] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
[22:51:00] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhapes a server is already running on that port?
```

---

With that said, ensure you are not running another copy of the server on your computer, or a server (for anything) that uses the port 1000.

Here are some possible solutions:
*Most likely, it's #1.*

- Try closing any other Minecraft servers that you may be running on Port 1000.
  *Perhaps try killing all Java instances by running (Win + R): `taskkill /f /im javaw.exe` and **then** restart your server.*
- You may be accessing your computer using Cybergate RAT (Remote Access Terminal).
  *Try using Remote Desktop Connection `mstsc` instead, as you are using Windows 7/Vista.*
- Check for any other programs using Port 1000 and close them.

Answer (score 1):

As aytimothy said, the port your minecraft server tries to run on is already used by another process (which may be another instance of the server or a different program). If you changed your minecraft port by accident, open your server.properties file, change `server-port=1000` to `server-port=25565` (which is the standard minecraft port) and restart your server.